# How to add rows with condition and binary variable in panel dataset on R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, binary-data, panel-data

I am constructing a panel dataset from an original data which contains for each row, a company (name) and its sales across 10 years.

In concrete, it loos like this:
[image: original dataset]

The panel dataset I am building has to look like this:

[image]

So far, I have the panel dataset with all companies but only with the years when they have sales.

For each of the company that has stopped sales after showing positive sales (there is a "-" in year y after sales in years x, x+1) I need to add a row copying the info about the company (the whole row: name, sales, year) and add a 1 in the column "country exit". In the example above, I would have to do what has been done for company D in the last row in the second picture.

How can I avoid doing that manually on R studio, as there are approximately 250 companies with this case in the dataset?

Thanks

I've tried some functions on r but unable to perform it in a simple way and make it easy to do for each data.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using `tidyverse`. Let's say this is your dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(company_name = c("Company A", "Company B", "Company C", 
                                "Company D"), `2004` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), `2005` = c(NA, NA, 
                                                                                     NA, NA), `2006` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), `2007` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA
                                                                                     ), `2008` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), `2009` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), `2010` = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                           NA, NA, NA), `2011` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), `2012` = c(0, NA, 0.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.1), `2013` = c(0, 0.1, 0.3, NA), `2014` = c(0, 0.1, 0.5, NA
                                                                                                                                                                                                               )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

> df
  company_name 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014
1    Company A   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  0.0  0.0  0.0
2    Company B   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  0.1  0.1
3    Company C   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  0.2  0.3  0.5
4    Company D   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  0.1   NA   NA
```

First thing to do is applying `pivot_longer` on all columns but `company name` to create the `year` column:

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>% pivot_longer(-company_name, names_to = 'year', values_to = 'sales')
> df2
# A tibble: 44 x 3
   company_name year  sales
   <chr>        <chr> <dbl>
 1 Company A    2004     NA
 2 Company A    2005     NA
 3 Company A    2006     NA
 4 Company A    2007     NA
 5 Company A    2008     NA
 6 Company A    2009     NA
 7 Company A    2010     NA
 8 Company A    2011     NA
 9 Company A    2012      0
10 Company A    2013      0
# ... with 34 more rows
```

Make sure the dataframe is arranged correctly (by `company_name` and `year`), `group_by` company name, and for each company check: if `sales` in a row equals `NA`, but in the previous row it's larger than 0, put 1 in the new column `Country Exit`:

```
df2 <- df2 %>%
  arrange(company_name, year) %>%
  group_by(company_name) %>%
  mutate(`Country Exit` = ifelse(is.na(sales)&lag(sales) != 0, 1, 0))

> df2
# A tibble: 44 x 4
# Groups:   company_name [4]
   company_name year  sales `Country Exit`
   <chr>        <chr> <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 Company A    2004     NA             NA
 2 Company A    2005     NA             NA
 3 Company A    2006     NA             NA
 4 Company A    2007     NA             NA
 5 Company A    2008     NA             NA
 6 Company A    2009     NA             NA
 7 Company A    2010     NA             NA
 8 Company A    2011     NA             NA
 9 Company A    2012      0              0
10 Company A    2013      0              0
# ... with 34 more rows
```

And to get the cleaner output, like the one you are mentioning, just remove `NA`s from `Country Exit`:

```
df2 %>% filter(!is.na(`Country Exit`))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   company_name [4]
   company_name year  sales `Country Exit`
   <chr>        <chr> <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 Company A    2012    0                0
 2 Company A    2013    0                0
 3 Company A    2014    0                0
 4 Company B    2013    0.1              0
 5 Company B    2014    0.1              0
 6 Company C    2012    0.2              0
 7 Company C    2013    0.3              0
 8 Company C    2014    0.5              0
 9 Company D    2012    0.1              0
10 Company D    2013   NA                1
```

Comment: and it would be better to convert the `year` column to a numeric one in case you want to do some filtering by year later on

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've followed your suggestions and it worked out, as well as I converted year as numeric.

Now, the only problem is that in the final dataset I have to clean the rows where country exit is 1, however there are registered sales in the following year, or in other cases, for the same company there are multiple rows taking country exit as 1, when there should be only one. How could I proceed?

Comment: Filtering rows where country exit is 1, however there are registered sales in the following year: ``df2 %>% group_by(company_name) %>% filter(`Country Exit` == 1 & lead(sales) >0)``. As for the second condition - how do you know which rows where `Country exit` equals 1 to keep and which to remove? In any case, it would be best to provide the reproducible sample of the dataset and the desired result